# Trying to pass Authorization Header from phpunit tests to code base and retrieve it [Slim PHP]

Tags: php, testing, header, phpunit, slim

I have slim php framework code but modified by a middleware that uses a php package as its service/controller but i have a problem beign able to send Authorization headers from php unit tests to the code itself the headers are not present when I print $_SERVER Array ... I cant retrieve the Headers from code ..

```
    $param1 = "param1";
    $param2 = "param2";
    $param3 = "param3";

    $env = Environment::mock(array(
        'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',
        'REQUEST_URI' => '/v1/url/to/api',
        'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
        'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token,
    ));

    $attributes = [
        $param1 => "100",
        $param2 => "0",
        $param3 => "1000",
    ];

    $req = Request::createFromEnvironment($env)->withParsedBody($attributes);
    $this->app->getContainer()['request'] = $req;
    $response = $this->app->run(true);

    $this->assertSame($response->getStatusCode(), 200);
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    $this->assertIsArray($result["content"]);
```

Edit !!!

I thought the Environment mock was a mock envrironment for testing but I discovered my DB is getting data inserted from the tests but i wonder why my code still doesn't see my Authorization headers from the test?

Comment: In Slim you may use the request object getServerParams() method instead.

Comment: I just realized my question was asked wrong. I need to send the authorization header using the mock env as my tests fail becuase the headers can't be seen in code. ?? @odan